# I overloaded operator<< to print all the elements in the vector, but It is not working?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, operator-overloading

I am working on vector pointers for a project, but I am not able to print all the elements in the vector.  I tried operator overloading, but it is not correct:

```
vector<list<int*>*> *v = new vector<list<int*>*> { 
    new list<int*> {new int(2), new int (7)}, 
    new list<int*> {new int(2), new int (7)}
};

for (int i = 0; i < v->size(); i++) {
    auto a = v[i].begin();
    while (a != v[i].end()) {
        cout << **a;
        a++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post images of code but add the actual code to the question. In addition take some time to read [ask] and then edit your question to clarify your problem.

Comment: Oh my god why so many pointers

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for(const auto& i : *v)
    for(const auto& j: *i)
        cout<<*j<<" ";
```

is there a reason for using so much pointers? your code could be much simpler like this:

```
   vector<list<int>> v {
   list<int> {2, 7},
   list<int> {2, 7}
};

for(const auto& i : v)
    for(const auto& j: i)
        cout<<j<<" ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just way too many pointers, but to rewrite your code correctly, in the same style that you did, try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < v->size(); i++) {
    auto a = (*v)[i]->begin();
    while (a != (*v)[i]->end()) {
        cout << **a;
        a++;
    }
}
```

Because `v` is a pointer to a vector, you have to write `(*v)[i]` to get an element out of the vector. Then since that element is itself a pointer to a list so you have to write `->begin()` to get the list iterator.

It is possible to write programs without so many pointers.